# Equality of $L_2$ norm on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: normed-spaces

Statement:
For a continuous function $y(t)$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, 
if $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^2(\tau)}{1+y^2(\tau)}d\tau<\infty$, $\int_0^{\infty}y^2(\tau)<\infty$.

The statement is true if $y(t)\in L_{\infty}$. What about if $y(t)$ is bounded for any finite time $t$? Is the above statement still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find continuous functions $y_n$, with support in $[0,1/n^2]$ such that $\int_0^{\infty}y_n^2(\tau) = n$.  And of course, $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y_n^2(\tau)}{1+y_n^2(\tau)}d\tau \le 1/n^2$.

Now let $y(x) = y_n(x-n)$ if $n \le x < n+1$ ($n \in \mathbb N$), and you have your counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for the counterexample. It seems that the support of $y_n$ should be $[1,1/n^2]$. And I have another question.

Comment: @caclo Thank you.  I corrected my answer.  What is your other question?

Comment: Does there exist a continuous and bounded function $\varphi (y^2)\geq 0$, and $\varphi (y^2)=0$ iff $y=0$, such that, if $\int_0^{\infty}y^2(\tau) d\tau<\infty$, $\int_0^{\infty}\varphi (y(\tau)) d\tau<\infty$, and if  $\int_0^{\infty}y^2(\tau) d\tau\rightarrow\infty$, $\int_0^{\infty}\varphi (y(\tau)) d\tau\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: I am rather sure the answer is "no."  Give me my 15 points by accepting my answer, and then I'll look for a proof.

Comment: Sorry, I am new on this website and I have only six points. When I get 15 points, I will vote for you surely. Thanks.

Comment: Probably a green check mark.

Comment: It seems to me that exactly the same example I gave in my original answer should work to disprove your second desired implication for any $\varphi$ satisfying your hypotheses.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thank you so much.